# mysql running total as view

Tags: mysql, view, subquery, cumulative-sum

I am still an sql greenhorn and try to convert this script, building a running total as view in mysql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table_account`;

CREATE TABLE `table_account`    
 (
  id    int(11),
  account   int(11),
  bdate   DATE,
  amount  DECIMAL(10,2)
 );

ALTER TABLE `table_account` ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);

INSERT INTO `table_account` VALUES (1, 1, '2014-01-01', 1.0);
INSERT INTO `table_account` VALUES (2, 1, '2014-01-02', 2.1);
INSERT INTO `table_account` VALUES (4, 1, '2014-01-02', 2.2);
INSERT INTO `table_account` VALUES (5, 1, '2014-01-02', 2.3);
INSERT INTO `table_account` VALUES (3, 1, '2014-01-03', 3.0);
INSERT INTO `table_account` VALUES (7, 1, '2014-01-04', 4.0);
INSERT INTO `table_account` VALUES (6, 1, '2014-01-06', 5.0);
INSERT INTO `table_account` VALUES (8, 1, '2014-01-07', 6.0);

SET @iruntot:=0.00;

SELECT
    q1.account, 
    q1.bdate,
    q1.amount,
    (@iruntot := @iruntot + q1.amount) AS runningtotal
FROM
   (SELECT
        account AS account,   
        bdate AS bdate,
        amount AS amount
    FROM  `table_account`
ORDER  BY account ASC, bdate ASC) AS q1
```

This is much more faster than building a sum over the whole history on each line.

The problems I cannot solve are:

- Set in view
- Subquery in view

I think it might be posssible to use some kind of JOIN instead of "SET @iruntot:=0.00;"
and use two views to prevent the need of a subquery.
But I do know how.

Will be happy for any hints to try.
Regards,
Abraxas

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Hi Strawberry,
I edited my question to provide an entre script (tested).
The resultset is exactly what I need, but as a view not as query.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't allow subqueries in the `from` clause for a view.  Nor does it allow variables. You can do this with a correlated subquery, though:

```
SELECT q.account, q.b_date, q.amount,
       (SELECT SUM(q2.amount)
        FROM myview1 q2
        WHERE q2.account < q.account OR
              q2.account = q.account and q2.date <= q.date
       ) as running total
FROM myview1 q;
```

Note that this assumes that the account/date column is unique -- no repeated dates for an account.  Otherwise, the results will not be exactly the same.

Also, it seems a little strange that you are doing a running total across all accounts and dates.  I might expect a running total within accounts, but this is how you formulated the query in the question.

Comment: Hi Gordon,
thanks, but this solutiion is where I came from.
Having 10.000 lines it is very slow.
That's why I tried it this way.
I changed my questiion an added the entire script.sTrst

Comment: sorry... pressed OK too soon

It needs 4 seconds for 10.000 records vs 1 minute.
The account shold be selected via WHERE CLAUSE in the query reading the desired view.
Due to the frontend (OpenOffice) I need the Wohle thing as a view, because OO cannot filter data basesd on native SQL commands...